# How to only restore a specific filegroup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

I am using SQL Server 2008R2 (but I can upgrade if necessary)

I have a database with multiple schemas and each schema is on a different filegroup (I wish I could just backup/restore a schema but that doesn't seem to be possible).

The recovery model is full.

I am performing backups of the filegroups.

How do I perform a filegroup to a previous state (without affecting the data on other filegroups?).
When I try to restore a file group I need to restore the transaction log which adds all changes since the last backup.

Is what I am asking even possible?

Answer (score 1):

A filegroup restore can be done on a database in FULL recovery model.  There are requirements and consequences of the restore.

1. You must be using Enterprise Edition.
2. The primary filegroup must be the first restore.
3. Filegroups that are not yet restored remain offline.

Start reading at this topic in MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177425(v=sql.105).aspx

Read the topic: "Piecemeal Restore Under the Full Recovery Model"

Comment: Also if I remember correctly you can restore individual read-only filegroups but have to restore all of the read/write filegroups together.